# Fields not deserialized when instance creator is registered with gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm using [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to deserialize objects, and I'm telling gson the interface class rather than the implementation class of the object I want. I register an `InstanceCreator` that constructs an instance of the implementation class.

This test demonstrates the problem that I encounter:

```
public class UnexpectedGsonBehaviorTest {

    public static interface Fruits {
        List<String> getFruitList();
    }

    public static class FruitsImpl implements Fruits {

        private List<String> fruitList;

        public List<String> getFruitList() {
            return fruitList;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "FruitsImpl{" + "fruitList=" + fruitList + '}';
        }

    }

    @Test
    public void testUseCustomFruitsInstanceCreator() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
          .registerTypeAdapter(Fruits.class, new InstanceCreator<Fruits>(){
            public Fruits createInstance(Type type) {
                return new FruitsImpl();
            }
        }).create();
        String fruitsJson = "{\"fruitList\": [\"apples\", \"pears\", \"bananas\"]}";
        System.out.println("input: " + fruitsJson);
        Fruits fruits = gson.fromJson(fruitsJson, Fruits.class);
        System.out.println("output: " + fruits);
        assertNotNull("expect non-null fruit list", fruits.getFruitList());
    }

}
```

I expect the list member of the `FruitsImpl` object to be deserialized, but it is not. The output is

```
input: {"fruitList": ["apples", "pears", "bananas"]}
output: FruitsImpl{fruitList=null}
```

and the assertion fails.

If I just use a default gson instance and `gson.fromJson(fruitsJson, FruitsImpl.class)`, the list field is correctly deserialized. Am I using gson wrong, or is there some other issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you debug it and put a breakpoint inside `createInstance` and step into the gson code you should see the problem.

After instantiation gson tries to populate all the bound fields in the `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory`. The bound fields map is empty in your case. This is because it can't inspect your interface for fields.

From `getBoundFields` in `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory`

```
Map<String, BoundField> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, BoundField>();
if (raw.isInterface()) {
  return result;
}
```

So the instance creator is more suitable if the type you told gson to deserialize has no zero arg constructor for gson to call.

Comment: Thanks. I expect your answer also applies to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739648/deserializing-json-string-containing-interfaces-not-working-in-java-using-gson-2