# How to Convert Java Interface to Json with Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have the following

```
public class Zoo{
  int id;
  String name;
  List<Animal> animalList;
  List<Bathroom> bathrooms;
}

public interface Animal{
  //animal has some common methods, but is mostly for naming
}

public class Cat implement Animal{
  int legs;//4
  String language;//meow
  String name;// owner
}

public class Horse implements Animal{
  String name;
  String owner;
  List<Race> races;//list of races this horse is scheduled to run
}
```

And I have many more types of `Animal`s that do completely different things from each other.

Now the problem is when I try to covert a Zoo object to json, the animal blocks are there but completely empty: no data. How do I solve this problem?

**conversion code**

```
Zoo zoo = createCompleteZooObject();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(zoo);
System.out.println(json)
```

Notice that I have no problem getting the list of bathrooms `List<Bathroom> bathrooms` as Json. Only the Animal (since it's an interface) is not showing up.

Comment: Please show us the code which does this conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Please, checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16400945/5695225). Gson cannot work with interface fields, because it does not knows which class it actualy should to use. Why not try to make an Animal abstract class?

Comment: Thanks for replying, but changing from interface to abstract class makes no difference. The question is essentially the same: how do I get polymorphism to work with Gson.

Comment: And I already looked at the link you provide. I cannot seem to get RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory even after using `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'`