# How to deserialize nested interface types with Gson

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I am trying to get Gson to deserialize a nested object in my JSON into a class that implements an interface.

Here is my interface:

```
public interface ActivationFunction {

    public float activate(float input);

}
```

I have an implementing class named LinearActivation and a Layer class that has a class variable of type ActivationFunction. Here is my JSON:

```
{
  "layers" : [
    {
      "input":6,
      "output":2,
      "weights":[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12]],
      "function":{"LinearFunction"
    }
  ]
}
```

I read this post: [Polymorphism with gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800433/polymorphism-with-gson) and I searched Gson docs here: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Writing-a-Deserializer

but I can't find any documentation on creating a typeHierarchyAdapter. I followed the example in the first link, but I am not sure how INSTANCE and CLASSNAME should be used within my JSON structure.

Here is the type hierarchy adapter:

```
public class ActivationFunctionAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<ActivationFunction> {

    private static final String CLASSNAME = "CLASSNAME";
    private static final String INSTANCE  = "INSTANCE";

    @Override
    public ActivationFunction deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
            JsonObject jsonObject =  json.getAsJsonObject();
            JsonPrimitive prim = (JsonPrimitive) jsonObject.get(CLASSNAME);
            String className = prim.getAsString();

            Class<?> klass = null;
            try {
                klass = Class.forName(className);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new JsonParseException(e.getMessage());
            }
            return context.deserialize(jsonObject.get(INSTANCE), klass);
    }

}
```

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by following the guide here:

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-deserialize-a-list-of-polymorphic-objects-with-gson

also same info can be seen in the answer by Perception in this question: [Using Gson with Interface Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396904/using-gson-with-interface-types)

Basically just had to add the RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory class to my project, (which the code is available in the extras package in the Gson github), then define a type token and use it. For example:

```
TypeToken<ActivationFunction> functionTypeToken = new TypeToken<ActivationFunction>() {};

RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<ActivationFunction> typeFactory = 
RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.of(ActivationFunction.class, "type")
                         .registerSubtype(LinearFunction.class, "linear");

final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(typeFactory).create();
```